# Increase impedance of a handset speaker

Tags: impedance-matching

I currently have a 300 ohm speaker for a handset. 
I am trying to increase its impedance to 1k ohm (audio frequency 1k). At the moment the audio level is to low. A resistor in series doesn't help as the audio level is low to begin with. 
I know I can do this with a transformer but I was wondering can it be achieved using inductors and capacitors?
Thanks
Hutto

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backwards, since what'll make the speaker louder is more current through its coil, and to get that to happen you'll have to lower the impedance of the load the amplifier's final is looking at.

That's what the transformer will do if you pick the turns ratio properly and if you don't overload the amp.

The same thing is true if your speaker's a piezo transducer, and in both cases what you need to do is to increase the voltage across the speaker's terminals.

You can also do the same thing if you can up the amp's gain and you've got enough supply headroom to keep the amp from running into the rails.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but the output from the audio socket in the spec sheet says to have a speaker with a 1 k ohm impedance. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Hutto: Post the data sheet, please.